# MongoDB: Which one is faster: findOne + if not exists insert or upsert?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to check if let's say 2000 URLs exist in a collection and insert the ones that are not already existing along with some other fields as a new document. I need to update only the timestamp field for the ones that are already exist. Usually new ones will be way less.

Currently I loop in async.each() and do an upsert for each and use updatedExisting field in the response to see if the URL is new. But maybe I should do findOne and insert or update. Another option is do a bulk find and do update for existing ones in async.each and do bulk insert for the new ones. Please advice! Thanks.

Comment: For 2000 urls I highly doubt there will be a difference. And as always - try it yourself and analyse your results.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Thanks. I'll check and post the result but could you tell any difference when considering the collection grows to a couple of million documents and the number of the URLs to check grow to 5000?

Comment: @user3211198 When you say you use async.each() you mean this is on application level in your code right? So you get documents from database and then loop right?

Comment: @Tim I get documents from 5 different RSS feeds. Then loop it to insert or update them in DB.

Comment: @user3211198 I have posted my answer below I hope that helps

Comment: @Tim thanks, "bulk" must be new, I need to upgrade mongo and try this.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think upsert would work well in your situation have a look at this page: [Mongo Bulk Upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/)

and this is a simple example of how it could work:

```
bulk.find( { item: "abc123" } ).upsert().replaceOne(
   {
     item: "abc123",
     status: "P",
     points: 100,
   }
);
bulk.execute();
```

I hope that helps.